# Remove value from bitwise or-combined integer?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Using the Bitwise Or operator you can combine integers, for example integers that are powers of 2, with each other, and later check if the returned int contains a specified value. But is there a proper way to remove values from the returned integer without combining a new one?

Currently I subtract the value that I want to remove from the combined integer, but does this work fine or can it cause issues? Or is there any more "proper" way of doing it?

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int combinedints = CombineIntegers(CombineIntegers(2, 8), 32); //Combine three integers.
    MessageBox.Show(combinedints.ToString()); //Shows 42.
    MessageBox.Show(RemoveInteger(combinedints, 8).ToString()); //Removes 8 - shows 34.
}

private int CombineIntegers(int a, int b)
{
    return a | b;
}

private int RemoveInteger(int a, int b)
{
    return a -= b;
}

private bool CheckInteger(int a, int b)
{
    return (a & b) == b;
}
```

Comment: *"combine integers, that are powers of 2, with each other'* - You can combine other integers too.

Comment: @GolezTrol : Changed... :)

Comment: What is the idea of `RemoveInteger`? If `unset`, it is very wrong.

Comment: @leppie : The idea is to remove a value from the main integer. If I combine 2, 8 and 32 it will equal to 42. Then I can use `RemoveInteger` to remove one of those values if I'd like to. (Such as 8).

Comment: @VisualVincent: But given `combine` is the implication a bitwise operation like your accepted answer implies? ;p

Comment: Okay this is getting ridiculous. My very old questions are starting to get downvoted... Hasn't the apparent hater got anything better to do? (I don't know if it's a hater, but this starts to feel really strange). I might be paranoid but this feels very "planned" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private int RemoveInteger(int a, int b)
{
    return a & ~b;
}
```

Comment: This would be logical, but the OP does not imply it.

Comment: @leppie : The check for a value is also logical. Does it matter, or...?

Comment: @VisualVincent: This is called bit operations or more correctly boolean mathematics (based on boolean algebra). Read up on it, it is quite fascinating what you can do with a series of ones and zeros :D